# In what way does `runpy` leave functions or classes in an incorrect state?

Tags: python, python-import, runpy

The documentation for `runpy` [warns](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/runpy.html)

> …any functions and classes defined by the executed code are not guaranteed to work correctly after a `runpy` function has returned.

What does that mean in practice? If they functioned normally during `runpy` execution, what can happen after `runpy` returns to make them go awry?

Comment: One factor could be that `sys.path`, `sys.argv` and `sys.modules` are modified during execution, then reverted when the function from `runpy` returns: https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/runpy.html

Comment: Please do not close-vote as "needs debugging details" for something that is not a debugging question.